# Compare specific recovery with random expectation

Tags: fishers-exact-test

i am reading a scientific article and i would like to understand how a specific statistical calculation is done. I am missing the principle and the method. If somebody could be so gentle to explain me which specific test has been done and why that would be great! i attach here the sentence:

> To compare the recovery of known BMD genes to what would be expected
>   by chance, we searched whole-body BMD data on 1928 mouse mutants
>   (selected at random with respect to known involvement in BMD) from the
>   International Mouse Phenotyping Consortium (IMPC) (Brown and Moore,
>   2012a; 2012b). In the IMPC, 6.3% (122 of 1928) of mouse knockouts
>   exhibited a BMD phenotype compared to 55% recovery of known regulators
>   of BMD in the OFM (OR=8.6, Fisher’s P=9.6 × 10−10), confirming that
>   with respect to the regulation of BMD, the OFM is not a random gene
>   set.

I attach here the reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5269473/pdf/nihms-824818.pdf

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

seems they did fisher's exact test. It would be heavy computation though, like a permutation test, [fisher's exact test, wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)

Comment: hi, why you say heavy computation? i understand the principle of fisher's but i dont see the point of applying this to this case to validate a run of predictions.

Comment: exact tests must generate the pool of possible results, hence demanding. Consider this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3167045/: "The statistical assessments of interest are generated for each permutation sample. If the treatment has an effect, then one would expect the observed pattern of results to occur rarely among these re-randomized samples. Fisher’s exact test, with which many researchers are familiar, is a permutation test for a single dichotomous endpoint.". I dont do gwas, but my immediate hunch for this kind of data would be an exact test, no study set up